# Is it necessary to create id column in SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello All I read somewhere in book or blog that there is rule-of-thumb in SQL that we must create ID column in each and every table with PRIMARY KEY and AUTO-INCREMENT attribute. What if i am using mobile number as a user id in my table. Should i create id column in my table or mobile number that is primary key in my table will be enough?

Comment: There's no such thumb rule. Yes, surrogate keys are OK, but they're not required, and where they are used, best practice is to provide a UNIQUE NATURAL KEY in addition. Mobile no is a poor key, because users occasionally change their numbers

Comment: @Strawberry: Best practice is to provide unique natural key in addition to a surrogate?  Can you cite some authority for that?

Comment: No, there is no specific rule to do this.   Depends on your data model.  However, if the user's mobile # can change, then that is probably not a good candidate for a PK, and you would want a separate ID.

Comment: I voted to close because this is primarily opinion based.  In my opinion -- based on my experience -- I put an autoincremented primary key in almost every table I create.

Comment: What about users with 2 numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not necessary, but for anything short of an association table it is recommended.

This Identity column provides a unique and unchanging Identifier of your data, it makes setting up foreign key relations quite easy.

An association table would not have one of these Identity columns because it has no data itself they generally consist of 2 or more foreign key columms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use phone number as primary key you can

```
create table MyData(
phonenumber int not null primary key,
fname varchar(25),
lname varchar(25)
...
)
```

But this may not be the best practice. Because a phone number might change. Once it belonged to customer A now belongs to customer B. With this model, you may eventually run into a problem where you can't pull your unique customer based on phone number only. If you add a self incrementing index as primary key, you can always refer to a unique customer by that ID. **This is safer, cleaner, more intuitive and easy to code against**. It esp. helps when you add foreign keys etc. By selecting a wrong primary key in the beginning, you may put yourself in big trouble may be an year or two down the road.

What you can also do is add a self incrementing index as primary key and put a UNIQUE constraint on phone number so the phone number must be unique in order to be entered into the DB. This is mainly done for data integrity for example if someone mistype something and now it matches another number, it will be caught right away. I would still not recommend this because you again might run into a problem where this constrain might catch a valid case.

So I would use self incrementing index as primary key to make thing simple and add a phone number field, which cannot be null (this would be another constraint :))

Answer (score 0):

As long as the key is unique - it can be used as a primary key. An additional ID column should be used when you don't have a column that can be used as a primary key either because it's not unique or can have NULL values. Also integer columns are preferred. So a phone number works.

Comment: "Also integer columns are preferred" if you're talking about 32 bit integers, that's just plain awful advice. If you're talking about 64 bit integers, that's your opinion; many seasoned DB administrators prefer `BINARY`, or a specialized type (like `UUID` in Postgres). Not to mention phone numbers should **NOT** be stored as ints, and an additional ID column can also be replaced by a composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When creating creating a SQL, It must have a unique identifiable key, meaning when you need to query records from that particular table, there must be unique column to make it easy for identification.

The primary key is a database term for that special, unique
value assigned to a particular row in a table.

In some rather special cases, you can even  create a primary key out of multiple columns instead of just one.They call it a composite key. In a nutshell  create your table and make your primary key that mobile number, if they are unique per person which I think is the case.

Let me give an example. the social security number is  set to be as primary key in Tables in USA and Europe too; and it is not an  incremental key.